# How to retreive texts and sounds of the briefings in Starcraft 1 and Starcraft BroodWar?

Tags: starcraft

I am trying to retrieve the text/sounds of the mission briefings in Starcraft 1 and Starcraft: BroodWar.

I have tried searching the web for "starcraft", "briefings", ".txt" and ".pdf" keywords but the search engine seems to not understand what I really mean.

Are the briefing texts somehow encoded into the game or they are more or less separated into some data file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a so called MPQ Editor. MPQ it is an archiving format like zip or rar developed by Blizzard. They store all their game data with it. There are different generations of this format. Think of it in generations (Diablo and Starcraft being one generation, Warcraft 3 another one etc...)

You need an editor like [Stormless MPQ Editor](http://www.angelfire.com/sc/mpq/) that supports your game and you need to find the MPQ file that holds the content you want. Open this file and extract the content. You will get all kinds of content, like MP3, WAV, JPG and a lot of script files.

I have only done this with Warcraft 3 back in the day, but it should work similarly with Starcraft I.

Comment: I've used this utility, but I haven't found briefings' sound files among other game sounds. Is it possible that briefing sounds have some wired format (not wav) or not listed in the listfile or even stored somewhere else?

Comment: Found out. But they are slightly unsorted. Is there a way to sort them as in game?

Answer (score 1):

<sub>The OP's answer, originally posted in the body of the question:</sub>

---

I found a [GameFAQ post](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/25418-starcraft/faqs/53600) which is the whole textual transcript of all Starcraft briefings.

As for the actual briefing sound files, they are present in the `starcraft.mpq` file (not `stardat.mpq`). To get at them you'll need a MPQ Editor as per @ayckoster's answer. However, the sounds themselves are slightly unordered (i.e. not ordered by mission)